# CeCreateDirectory via RAPI fails, not sure why

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, rapi

I have the following code:

```
  [DllImport("rapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CeCreateDirectory(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);
```

and in a function I've attempted, amongst other things, the following:

```
CeCreateDirectory( "\\fail\\", ptr )
CeCreateDirectory( "C:\\fail\\", ptr )
CeCreateDirectory( "\\fail", ptr )
CeCreateDirectory( "C:\\fail", ptr )
```

Every time the function returns false, I just want to create a directory on the device but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Did you first call [CeRapiInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922061.aspx) (or CeRapiInitEx)?  And why reinvent the wheel?  All of this RAPI stuff is already wrapped and open-sourced in the [OpenNETCF Desktop Communication library](http://rapi.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Windows CE, but Windows Mobile doesn't support the "C:\" part.

```
CeCreateDirectory( "C:\\fail\\", ptr )
```

Have you tried using the [System.IO.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class?

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("\\fail");
```

May also need to leave the last "\" character off, too.

Comment: All versions of CE have no support for drive letters, so you're right there.  This is RAPI (run on desktop through ActiveSync) code, though so System.IO is not going to help.

Comment: Could it be that extra `\\` character that he is sticking on the end? (obviously, I don't use RAPI)

Comment: dunno - my guess is that he didn't initialize RAPI, but without code we're only guessing.